# Enable or disable API parameter

Tags: jmeter

I want to disable the specific  parameter in some case while posting data.

Is there any way to control post data parameter in JMeter?

For example in below screenshot I don't want to send `data[paymentid][]` in specific case.is there any way to control using preprocessor or using any other option?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To add a parameter:

   ```
   def arg = new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument('data[paymentid][]', vars.get('payment_id'), '=', false, 'text/plain')
   sampler.getArguments().addArgument(arg)
   ```
2. To remove a parameter

   ```
   sampler.getArguments().removeArgument('data[paymentid][]')
   ```

Where `sampler` is a shorthand for [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html?org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html)

Both code snippets are to be put into the [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor), the PreProcessor should be added as a child of the HTTP Request sampler you need to modify (or if there are more than one sampler - put it at the same level as these samplers, see [JMeter Scoping Rules - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) for more information)

Comment: do i need to import anylibrary for this? because i tried using your solution but it is not working

Comment: You don't need to import anything. Which solution? How exactly "is not working"?

Answer (score 0):

You can add parameters in [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) using `sampler`

```
sampler.addArgument("data[paymentid][]", vars.get("payment_id"));
```

> sampler - (Sampler)- gives access to the current sampler

You can add if condition to add parameter